# Typescript convert object to another interface that extends it

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm currently getting an api response as below

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "March 2022",
  "metrics": [
    {
      "name": "Visual",
      "priority": "normal"
    },
    {
      "name": "Spoken",
      "priority": "high"
    }
  ]
}
```

which i'm mapping to a interface as follows

```
interface Report {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  metrics: Array<{
    name: string;
    priority: string;
  }>;
}
```

But for i have a form for which i need validation so i've created another interface which extends Report and has error properties

```
interface ReportForm extends Report {
  nameError: string;
  metrics: Array<{
    name: string;
    priority: string;
    nameError: string;
    priorityError: string;
  }>;
}
```

But I'm unable to convert to the Report object to ReportForm .

So each time i get an API response with the report array I wish to convert it to ReportForm type with the error properties.

I tried creating a new object by mapping the similar properties and adding the new "errors" properties, but i'm unable to modify that object. Getting "Cannot assign to read only property 'nameError' of object"  error.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that demonstrates the problem you're running into for others when they paste it into their own IDEs.  If the problem is modifying an object, show that to us.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have your actual code, I can only assume how it looks. But still, you can find in the snippet below how I'm able to convert first from json to the ReportForm type, and then augment the missing error fields (both for the root one and for the fields inside the `metrics` nested array of objects):

```
const mockResponse = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'March 2022',
  metrics: [
    {
      name: 'Visual',
      priority: 'normal',
    },
    {
      name: 'Spoken',
      priority: 'high',
    },
  ],
};

interface Report {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  metrics: Array<{
    name: string;
    priority: string;
  }>;
}

const responseAsReport = mockResponse as Report;
console.log('report', responseAsReport); // it works as expected

interface ReportForm extends Report {
  nameError: string;
  metrics: Array<{
    name: string;
    priority: string;
    nameError: string;
    priorityError: string;
  }>;
}

const reportForm = { ...mockResponse } as ReportForm;
reportForm.nameError = 'some root nameError';
reportForm.metrics.forEach((metric) => {
  metric.nameError = 'some metric nameError';
  metric.priorityError = 'some metric priorityError';
});
console.log('reportForm1', reportForm); // it works as expected
```

---

Screenshot:

[image]

---

Stackblitz working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-bgsu2k?file=index.ts

I hope this helps.